# Copy sevaral text input values into a single textarea

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Im working for a school project and Im stuck and I was not able to find a script snippet or an answer to my problem in google.

After uploading an image the script shows the thumbnail and the link to that image inside a text field.

```
<input type="text" id="imlink" name="imlink" onclick="s(this);" size="70" value="'.SURL.''.$imagesfolder.'/' . $bigboy . '">
```

My problem is that when I upload 10 images it takes too much time to copy each field, so what I want to do is to show the "value" of all those 10 text inputs into one single textarea.

```
<textarea>
my_image1.jpg
my_image2.jpg
my_image3.jpg
my_image4.jpg
my_image5.jpg
</textarea>
```

Is there any solution for my problem ?

thanks in advance !

Comment: Sure there is if you show us your code & markup.

Comment: Shef, theres no code. Its as simple as that. Its a php script that uploads multiple images. After uploading a thumbnail is generated and a link to the original picture right near the thumbnail inside a text input. I want to copy all the links from those text inputs into a single textarea.

Comment: Okay, good luck with it then. I asked you to help us help you by sharing the HTML markup (or a sample) so we could come up with a solution tailored to your needs.

Answer (score 0):

The `.value` property can be used to extract the values for each `<input />` field. These values can then be inserted into the `<textarea />`:

```
var values = "";
$("input").each(function(i) {
    values += (i > 0 ? "\n" : "") + this.value;
});
$("textarea").val(values);
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jensgram/WFp9N/).

(This can be wrapped in a function and attached as a "change event handler" on the `<input />` elements.)

Comment: Thanks jensgram, but unfortunatly I dont have the knowledge to do that. Thansk anyway !

Comment: @elias Unfortunately I am not able to provide a better example based on your question :-S

Comment: -> Thanks, after spending a couple of hours reading some jquery articles I found the way to make it work. Thanks for pointing the right direction !